# How to suppress exception message box EIdConnClosedGracefully from thread in DataSnap

Tags: c++builder, indy, datasnap

I'm  trying to build DataSnap server in C++ Builder XE as Windows Form Application. I use TIdSchedulerOfThreadPool as described here http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/datasnap_deployment_performance.html. Under have load I get lots of EIdConnClosedGracefully exceptions which is probably normal, but the problem is that I get this exceptions as MessageBoxes from threads. I look for some events where i can suppress this messageboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing the messageboxes appear only while running your app inside of the debugger, or do you see them while running the app outside of the IDE as well?  Inside the debugger is normal behavior, since they are exceptions afterall.  The debugger shows popup messages for raised exceptions unless you tell it to ignore them.  But outside of the IDE, the only way you can be seeing messagebox from worker threads is if either your own code is catching the exceptions and displaying the messageboxes yourself, or else DataSnap is showing them internally.  EIdConnClosedGracefully is an Indy exception, and DataSnap does use Indy internally, but it is very unlikely that DataSnap would be displaying its own messageboxes.  Indy certainly does not ever display a messagebox.

Comment: I've added bug report http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=112154 It was fixed in XE3 http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=97194  It's never ending story. XE3 fixes one issue and introduces new one. R.I.P DataSnap

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing messageboxes outside of the IDE too. It comes from TWebRequestHandler (DataSnap). Here are stacktrace of thread that displays that messagebox:

```
:7c90e514 ntdll.KiFastSystemCallRet
:7e369418 user32.WaitMessage + 0xc
:7e3749c4 ; C:\WINDOWS\system32\user32.dll
:7e38a956 ; C:\WINDOWS\system32\user32.dll
:7e38a2bc ; C:\WINDOWS\system32\user32.dll
:7e3b63fd user32.MessageBoxTimeoutW + 0x7a
:7e3a0853 user32.MessageBoxExW + 0x1b
:7e3b6579 user32.MessageBoxW + 0x45
:004D6BBD Sysutils::ShowException(ExceptObject=????, ExceptAddr=????)
:0082b248 ; Webreq::TWebRequestHandler::HandleException
:0082b06f ; Webreq::TWebRequestHandler::HandleRequest
:0043dbdf ; Idhttpwebbrokerbridge::_16464
:0043dd23 Idhttpwebbrokerbridge::TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge::DoCommandGet + 0x23
:0068AB4D Idcustomhttpserver::TIdCustomHTTPServer::DoExecute(Self=:00E9B9D0, AContext=:00F13660)
:0063F09A Idcontext::TIdContext::Run(Self=????)
:0049F9CD Classes::ThreadProc(Thread=:00ECA260)
:004EF72E System::ThreadWrapper(Parameter=:00F1EF10)
:7c80b729 ; C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
```

Comment: Then it is a bug in `TWebRequestHandler::HandleException()`, as it should not be calling `ShowException()` inside of a worker thread. Please [file a bug report](http://qc.embarcadero.com) to Embarcadero.